# Configure Kafka consumer acknowledgement mode for Spring Boot Kafka project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot version 1.5.2.RELEASE along with Spring Kafka version 1.1.2.RELEASE.
Via the application.properties file I do see available options (spring.kafka.consumer.*) to configure Kafka Consumer.

What I'm not able to find though is a way to configure the acknowledgement mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder** to streaming messages. In that case

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and configure consumer like this.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer..
```

and producer like this

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer..
```

to more detail follow [this](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iel2Q6ZgZr4)

Comment: Is there a solution without involving Spring Cloud Stream?

Comment: Could you please point out where in that referenced link does it mention about configuring the acknowledgement mode?

Comment: Got it thanks - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Can you post the answer here